# How do I sign a debuggable android apk in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I have a debuggable apk of an app created outside android studio, I need to sign it to make it a release apk, I have created the keystore file. Is there a way I can do this by importing the apk into Android Studio?

Comment: You can try: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner

Comment: I can't find the apksigner utility anywhere in my Android studio installation.

Comment: I used jarsigner, then zipalign, on uploading to playstore, got the erro message : "You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?"